# Make object method a variable in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Say, I have a constructor called `Animal`, that has two prototype methods, `foo` and `bar`.

I create a new object:

```
const animal = new Animal()
```

I could call:

```
animal.foo()
```

or

```
animal.bar()
```

Can I replace the two methods with another method (`baz`)?

Like:

```
animal.baz()
```

So depending on the context, I want to assign either `foo` or `bar` to `baz`.

Comment: What is the context that you are checking against? Is it a class, object, string/number id to some object?

Comment: yes, you can. but what for?

Comment: @NinaScholz Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

The object-oriented way to do this would be to create two subclasses, one for each context. In each one, you would define the `baz` method to simply pass its arguments on to `this.foo` or `this.bar`, respectively.

You could also dynamically define `baz` on objects using `animal.baz = Animal.<foo|bar>`. However, that strategy would be less maintainable (you would have to define that every time you instantiated an object), and less performant (interpreters are optimized for objects with unchanging properties).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what form the context is in, a simple way you could do this would be to pass the context (in whatever form) in the constructor, store it in the object, and when `baz` is called, check the stored context and act accordingly. This is also pretty flexible:

```
// ES6
class Animal {
    constructor(context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    foo() {
        ...
    }
    bar() {
        ...
    }
    baz() {
        if(context == "some string id maybe?") {
            return this.foo();
        } else if(context == 13523) { // some integer id
            return this.foo();
        } else if(context === someContextObject) { // some context object
            return this.bar();
        } else {
            return this.foo();
        }
    }
}

//Vanilla

const Animal = function(context) {
    this.context = context;
}
Animal.prototype.foo = function() {
    ...
}
Animal.prototype.bar = function() {
    ...
}
Animal.prototype.baz = function() {
    if(context == "some string id maybe?") {
        return this.foo();
    } else if(context == 13523) { // some integer id
        return this.foo();
    } else if(context === someContextObject) { // some context object
        return this.bar();
    } else {
        return this.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? :D

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(isAgressive) {
    this.seesMe = isAgressive ? this.attack : this.flee;
  }
  
  attack = function () {
    console.log('attack!');
  }
  
  flee() {
    console.log('cya!');
  }
}

const zebra = new Animal(false);
const lion = new Animal(true);

zebra.seesMe();
lion.seesMe();
```